# Bypassing OPTIONS in REST

Tags: c#, ajax, rest

Is there a way to post from one domain to another without OPTIONS?  I have a POST from domain A to domain B which becomes OPTIONS when I try to run it.  Is there a way around that?  For example, can I write the service on domain B to accept a POST without asking for OPTIONS?

Comment: How does the target machine expect the `POST` message to look? I've used REST countless times to interop with for example C# and PHP and I  have never heard of this OPTIONS requirement you speak of. Could it be that the target machine is running some specific software that expects these parameters? If so, update your question with them.

Comment: I think you need more details - a POST doesn't require an OPTIONs request - those are two separate http requests.  Are you use a framework that happens to do both?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about doing the POST in a browser...

In that case, if using AJAX, and it's cross-domain, you will need the OPTION request, unless you disable web security.

One option would be to create a hidden `iframe`, add a `form` with the right `action` and `method=POST` and then submit the form using `form.submit();`

Why not use OPTION though?

Another option would be to reverse proxy the request through your domain. Send the POST to your own web server, which forwards the request to the other domain, and returns its response.